# is there a way to halt relationship execution when updating in spring data JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Question:

> Table A and table B have got one to many relationship.

The following is the relationship

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Spares> sparesList = new ArrayList<Spares>();
```

If it holds same `name`, `quantity` and `company` in table `B` fields should update count in that case???

```
Optional<Spares> o = sparesServiceImpl.findByNameAndQuantityAndCompany(name, quantity, company);
if(o.isPresent())
{
    Spares dbSpare = o.get();
                
    LOGGER.info("Spare already present so got to update, spare:"+dbSpare);
    sparesServiceImpl.update(dbSpare.getId(), dbSpare);
}
else
{
    LOGGER.info("Got added through relation, spare:"+s);
}
```

Is there a way to halt relationship execution when updating in spring data JPA???

This is what is log

```
2022-02-27 16:11:53.369  INFO 19712 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.m.a.s.services.SparesServiceImpl       : Updated one in DB:Spares [id=1, Name=Engine oil, Quantity=18 liters, Company=gulf, SuppliedBy=Patre, PurchasingCost=27000, purchasingCostPerPc=null, SellingCost=0, SellingCostPerPc=null, Count=10, Product ID=1, Bill Receivable =null, Bill Payable =null and updatedCost =false]
Hibernate: update spares set last_modified_date=?, count=? where id=?
Hibernate: select spares0_.id as id1_7_, spares0_.created_by as created_2_7_, spares0_.created_date as created_3_7_, spares0_.last_modified_by as last_mod4_7_, spares0_.last_modified_date as last_mod5_7_, spares0_.company as company6_7_, spares0_.count as count7_7_, spares0_.name as name8_7_, spares0_.bill_payable_id as bill_pa17_7_, spares0_.product_id as product_9_7_, spares0_.purchasing_cost as purchas10_7_, spares0_.purchasing_cost_per_pc as purchas11_7_, spares0_.quantity as quantit12_7_, spares0_.bill_receivable_id as bill_re18_7_, spares0_.selling_cost as selling13_7_, spares0_.selling_cost_per_pc as selling14_7_, spares0_.supplied_by as supplie15_7_, spares0_.updated_cost as updated16_7_ from spares spares0_ where spares0_.name=? and spares0_.quantity=? and spares0_.company=?
2022-02-27 16:11:53.369  INFO 19712 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.m.a.c.BillReceivableController         : Spare already present so got to update, spare:Spares [id=2, Name=Steering oil, Quantity=5 liters, Company=gulf, SuppliedBy=Patre, PurchasingCost=15000, purchasingCostPerPc=null, SellingCost=0, SellingCostPerPc=null, Count=10, Product ID=1, Bill Receivable =null, Bill Payable =null and updatedCost =false]
2022-02-27 16:11:53.369  INFO 19712 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.m.a.s.services.SparesServiceImpl       : in service impl update:2
2022-02-27 16:11:53.369  INFO 19712 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.m.a.s.services.SparesServiceImpl       : in service impl update:2, PC:15000, PC per piece:null, SC:0 and SC per piece:null
2022-02-27 16:11:53.369  INFO 19712 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.m.a.s.services.SparesServiceImpl       : Updated one in DB:Spares [id=2, Name=Steering oil, Quantity=5 liters, Company=gulf, SuppliedBy=Patre, PurchasingCost=15000, purchasingCostPerPc=null, SellingCost=0, SellingCostPerPc=null, Count=20, Product ID=1, Bill Receivable =null, Bill Payable =null and updatedCost =false]
Hibernate: update spares set last_modified_date=?, count=? where id=?
2022-02-27 16:11:53.385  INFO 19712 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.m.a.c.BillReceivableController         : balance:44000
2022-02-27 16:11:53.385  INFO 19712 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.m.a.s.s.BillReceivableServiceImpl      : In service impl...
Hibernate: insert into billreceivable (created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date, address, balance, consultee, contact, last_bill_amount, last_bill_date, last_paid_amount, last_paid_date, total_bill_amount, total_paid_amount, vendor) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert 
into spares (created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date, company, count, name, bill_payable_id, product_id, purchasing_cost, purchasing_cost_per_pc, quantity, bill_receivable_id, selling_cost, selling_cost_per_pc, supplied_by, updated_cost) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-02-27 16:11:53.385 ERROR 19712 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry 'Engine oil-18 liters-gulf' for key 'UKqarnb1pc7e9px6w0lsx5fjlpp'
2022-02-27 16:11:53.406 DEBUG 19712 --- [io-8080-exec-10] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Using @ExceptionHandler com.mycompany.app.exception.ControllerExceptionHandler#handleAllUncaughtException(Exception, WebRequest)
2022-02-27 16:11:53.416 ERROR 19712 --- [io-8080-exec-10] c.m.a.e.ControllerExceptionHandler       : Unknown error occurred

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UKqarnb1pc7e9px6w0lsx5fjlpp]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:298) ~[spring-orm-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Can you show me your `select` and `update` query?

Comment: Won't be any insert becoz insertion happens on relationship and updation simple call to update api in spring data JPA.

Comment: Can you show me your entity?